# 0-1 Knapsack Problem Python: Why are we returning the max value

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, knapsack-problem

```
# A naive recursive implementation 
# of 0-1 Knapsack Problem 
  
# Returns the maximum value that  
# can be put in a knapsack of  
# capacity W 
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n): 
  
    # Base Case 
    if n == 0 or W == 0 : 
        return 0
  
    # If weight of the nth item is  
    # more than Knapsack of capacity W,  
    # then this item cannot be included  
    # in the optimal solution 
    if (wt[n-1] > W): 
        return knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1) 
  
    # return the maximum of two cases: 
    # (1) nth item included 
    # (2) not included 
    else: 
        return max( 
            val[n-1] + knapSack( 
                W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1),  
                knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)) 
  
# end of function knapSack 
  
# To test above function 
val = [60, 100, 120] 
wt = [10, 20, 30] 
W = 50
n = len(val) 
print knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

Why are we returning the max value? I mean it is working fine if we just return. The other thing is just a recursive call if that element's weight is greater then our capacity right?

```
return val[n-1] + knapSack( W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1)
```

Comment: Try tests where all your inputs aren't all sorted in ascending values.

Comment: all the inputs? weight and values?

Comment: If the weights must maintain a position in line with the values, then just reorder them in line with the out of order values. It'll help you see cases where the `max` is important.